# Redis with igbinary in Wordpress PHP Docker container

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, redis, igbinary

I would like to allow my wordpress instance to access database content via Redis, using the igbinary serializer. I am using the Redis Cache Plugin for Worpdress by Till Krüss.
According to my understanding the containers should be in the following way:

- redis:alpine (https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) No modifications to be done here, right?
- wordpress:php7.4-fpm-alpine (https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) Redis support with igbinary should be included here right?

How to properly include Redis with igbinary support with the wordpress iamge? I tried the following:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.4-fpm-alpine
RUN set -xe \
&& apk update \
&& apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS \
&& pecl install -o -f igbinary \
&& cd /usr/src/ \
&& pecl bundle redis \
&& docker-php-ext-configure /usr/src/redis --enable-redis-igbinary \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) /usr/src/redis \
&& docker-php-ext-enable redis \
&& docker-php-ext-enable igbinary \
&& apk del .phpize-deps
```

I read, that pecl is outdated and should not be used anymore (Instead use pickle or composer, which however do not seem to offer the right packages)

So the question is: How does a Dockerfile have to look like to allow the use of redis with igbinary serializer using modern standards?

I hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.4-fpm-alpine
RUN set -xe \
&& apk update \
&& apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS \
# && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
&& wget https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/pickle/releases/latest/download/pickle.phar \
&& chmod +x pickle.phar \
&& mv pickle.phar /usr/local/bin/pickle \
&& pickle install -n igbinary \
&& docker-php-ext-enable igbinary \
&& echo "--enable-redis-igbinary" > cfg-options.txt \
&& pickle install --with-configure-options cfg-options.txt redis \
&& docker-php-ext-enable redis \
&& apk del .phpize-deps \
&& rm -rf cfg-options.txt \
&& php -m | grep igbinary \
&& php -m | grep redis \
&& php -i | grep igbinary \
&& php -i | grep redis \
#&& CLI_VERSION=$(wp cli info | grep "WP-CLI version" | cut -d$'\t' -f2) \
#&& if [ "${CLI_VERSION}" = "2.4.0" ]; then wp cli update --nightly --yes; fi
```

It is working when using pickel and respecting the order of enabling igbinary extension before redis extension.